# what's the best (most efficient) way in asp .net to return a whole page into tabbed content?

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

what i want to do is every time i click on a tab, the content area is replaced by pretty much a whole new page.  i don't want a full page load so i want to do it in ajax, but i'm used to sending back small jason data via page methods.  i'm not sure how i would construct a whole new page and return that via ajax and i would like to simply assign the whole content returned to a div and be done with it.  what's the best way to do this with the least amount of overhead (i know there are some inefficient ways the scriptmanager does ajax)?

or is it better to load the tabbed content in an iframe?

fyi i'm already using jquery to call lightweight pagemethods on my asp net page and that works great.

Comment: did somem more researching and it looks like i'm going to go with using an HTTP handler that returns markup using an asp net page template.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.net and also Asp.net Ajax Control Toolkit you can use from AjaxControlToolkit Tab control to implement your approach. (in any tab you have to put a new page or a Module (i recommand to use Module))

If not you can use a Asp.net MultiView Control and some Button which whenever User click on a button you change the MultiView ActiveViewIndex (via ajax AsynchPostback)

and finally you can use some div and control them via javascript

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to use the jQuery Tab UI

** EDIT: this will work if the pages are all from the same domain as they are being loaded via AJAX (security restriction applies). If it is necessary to load pages from other domains, then a cross domain policy may have to be implemented (requiring permission form the other domains) or use of local proxy script to request the data and relay it to the javascript. (JSONP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP is an exception.)

Check this link for a demo:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ajax.html

NB: You will have to download the additional jQuery UI libraries and include the Tabs widget.

Get those here: http://jqueryui.com/download

The code will look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.all.css">
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        ajaxOptions: {
            error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                $( anchor.hash ).html(
                    "Couldn't load this tab.");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>


<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.aspx">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.aspx">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.aspx">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```